# Sequelize association with alias does not exist

Tags: node.js, database, express, sequelize.js, relationship

I know there has been a whole bunch of such questions and I tried many solutions I could find but none seem to work for me.

I have two models, Player and PlayerSkill.

Player:

```
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';
import database from '../index';

const Player = database.define(
     'player',
   {
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    name: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING(200),
      allowNull: false,
    },
    position: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING(200),
      allowNull: false,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: false,
  }
);

Player.associate = models => {
  models.Player.hasMany(models.PlayerSkill, {
    as: 'playerskills',
    foreignKey: 'playerId',
  });
};

export default Player;
```

My PlayerSkill model:

```
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';
import database from '../index';

const PlayerSkill = database.define(
  'playerSkill',
  {
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    skill: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING(200),
      allowNull: false,
    },
    value: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    },
    playerId: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: false,
  }
);

PlayerSkill.associate = models => {
  models.PlayerSkill.belongsTo(models.Player, {
    foreignKey: 'playerId',
    allowNull: false,
  });
};

export default PlayerSkill;
```

I need to fetch the data in a way that it looks like this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "player name 2",
    "position": "midfielder",
    "playerSkills": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "skill": "attack",
            "value": 60,
            "playerId": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "skill": "speed",
            "value": 80,
            "playerId": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

And here is my fetch funtion:

```
// Create new player
  await Player.create(req.body)
    .then(() => {
      PlayerSkill.bulkCreate(skills);
    })
    .then(() => Player.findAll({ include: ['playerskills'] }))
    .then(result => console.log(result))
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(400).send({
        message: err.message || 'Error occurred while creating player',
      });
    });
```

Postman request:

```
{
    "name": "player1",
    "position": "defender",
    "playerSkills": [
        {
            "skill": "strength",
            "value": 90,
            "playerId": 1
        },
        {
            "skill": "speed",
            "value": 90,
            "playerId": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

I don't understand what am I doing wrong here. I keep getting the following error:

```
{
    "message": "Association with alias \"playerskills\" does not exist on player"
}
```

Comment: Show the code where you register models and their associations

Comment: This was part of a coding challenge. I don't think the association is defined. As a work around, I used `Player.hasMany(PlayerSkill, { onDelete: 'cascade' });` instead. But this then changes the whole structure that was given to me.

Comment: You just need a place where you register models and call models' `associate` methods

Comment: I see. I'll look it up how it works. It's a bit strange that they would give you broken code in a coding challenge. The instructions asked not to modify this file so it doesn't make sense

Comment: What file are you talking about? You didn't show the main module where you register associations. There should be a place where `associate` methods are called

Comment: Here's the full code.

https://github.com/SambaGod/TeamSelector

You can see both models Player and PlayerSkill in src/db/model
I modified Player model so there is no associate anymore but PlayerSkill still have the associate method. But I don't think this method was defined anywhere

Comment: I found association registration in `db/model/index.js`

Comment: Then why is the error message saying association does not exist?

Comment: See the answer below

Answer (score 0):

You should transform the direct call of `hasMany` in `Player` module into `associate` method just like you have in `PlayerSkill`  model module. And don't forget to remove `PlayerSkill` import line from `Player` module.

**model/player.js**

```js
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';
import database from '../index';

const Player = database.define(
  'player',
  {
...
);

Player.associate = models => {
  Player.belongsTo(models.PlayerSkill, {
    foreignKey: 'playerId',
    onDelete: 'cascade'
  });
};
```

Make sure you have the same `foreignKey` option in both paired associations.
And use models from one already defined module `index`:

```js
import { Player, PlayerSkill } from '../../db/model/index';

export default async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const players = await Player.findAll({ include: PlayerSkill });
...
```

Comment: As you can see in my question, this is exactly how it used to be and it wasn't working. That's why I switched to direct usage of hasMany

Comment: Can you output a model instance associations right before calling findAll?